# Unable to return json in symfony 2

Tags: php, json, rest, symfony

This is my controller

```
public function index2Action($name)
    {   
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  $test = $em->getRepository('RestWebServiceBundle:Test')->findall();
  return new Response(json_encode(array('locations' => $test)));

    }
```

When I go to the URL I get:

```
{"locations":[{}]}
```

However when I use:

```
public function index2Action($name)
    {   
$name ="Adam";
  return new Response(json_encode(array('locations' => $name)));

    }
```

I get the JSON.

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to get JSON in the first scenario.

UPDATE: I have verified that the $test variable is indeed not empty and when I do a print_r on it, it shows me the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Rest\WebServiceBundle\Entity\Test Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 1
            [title:protected] => test title
            [author:protected] => test author
            [blog:protected] => this is the blog
            [tags:protected] => 
            [comments:protected] => 
            [created:protected] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2012-05-13 00:00:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => America/Chicago
                )

            [updated:protected] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2012-05-13 00:00:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => America/Chicago
                )

        )

)
null
```

Comment: check why $test is coming back empty. You ARE getting json back in the first example. PHP can only output what you tell it to, and most likely $test is coming back as an empty object. So... figure out why.

Comment: I verified that I am getting a valid record set in test. Almost feel like it is something to do with json_encode not liking the resultset from the findall.

Comment: json-encode will convert an object, but only if that object provides a "stringify" method.

Comment: Marc, I have updated my question above. Still strange.

Comment: as per http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php, protected members are visible only within the class itself and any descendants. json_encode won't be able to see them since it's outside the class.

Comment: ahhhh haa! That could be it. Thanks for looking that up Marc.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you to use the serializer for return entities. have a look at the serializer component or the jmsserializerbundle.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $obj = $test;

        $serializer = new Serializer(
            array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()),
            array('json' => new JsonEncoder())
        );
        $json = $serializer->serialize($obj, 'json');

        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($json);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this by using getArrayResult() instead of getResult() in my repository class & it works

Comment: @gunar Why do you think that this is not (at least an attempt to) an answer?

Comment: @MathiasMüller: re-reading this all over again and it makes sense. The Vote will be retracted. Thanks for noticing!